# Où s'arrête le complément d'objet direct?

Tags: grammaire, compléments

En aidant mes enfants avec leur devoirs de grammaire (COD, COI), j'ai commencé à avoir des doutes sur où s'arrête un COD.

> Les élèves ont préparé un gâteau au chocolat.

Je cherche le COD en posant la question *"quoi? qui?"*, donc *"Les élèves ont préparé quoi?"*

- *"un gâteau"*, avec *"au chocolat"* comme COI,
- ou bien *"un gâteau au chocolat"*?

Un autre exemple:

> J'ai trouvé une pomme rouge ressemblant à une poire.

Est-ce que le COD sera le nom *"une pomme"*, le groupe nominal *"une pomme rouge"* ou la structure complète *"une pomme rouge ressemblant à une poire"*?

Où s'arrête un COD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pour détecter un COD, il faut poser la question *qui* ou *quoi*. Pour détecter un COI, il faut poser la question *à qui*, *à quoi*, *de qui* ou *de quoi*.

Mais attention, pour qu'il n'y ait pas de confusion, il faut poser ces questions tout en commençant par le début de la phrase SUJET + VERBE + Le reste (à qui, à quoi, de qui, de quoi, quoi, qui) !

Prenons l'exemple que tu as cité "Les élèves ont préparé un gâteau au chocolat".
La question à poser est : *les élèves ont préparé QUOI ?* La réponse est donc *un gâteau au chocolat*. Mais, on ne pose pas la question un gâteau à quoi, d'où la confusion que tu as eue en pensant que *au gâteau* est un COI, ce qui est naturellement faux.

Pour ton deuxième exemple: *J'ai trouvé une pomme rouge ressemblant à une poire*. On pose la question, j'ai trouvé quoi ? Et la réponse est *une pomme rouge ressemblant à une poire*

En d'autres termes, le COD peut être simple à savoir un nom, comme il peut être sous plusieurs natures grammaticales plus au moins longues, *infinitif, pronom, groupe nominal, proposition, etc*. Tant qu'on parle de choses décrivant le nom simple en question, tout cela fera partie du COD.

Answer (score 5):

Le COD peut être un nom ou un groupe nominal : « Je fais souvent **ce rêve étrange et pénétrant** »
Pour les deux exemples, le COD est le groupe nominal « un gâteau au chocolat » et « une pomme rouge ressemblant à une poire »